# Can I perform many asynchronous database requests without deeply nesting my code?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I'm sort of new to programming asynchronously. I've run into a situation where I need to perform 8 database lookups in a loop. I'm not sure how to accomplish this-- my database library returns the data in a callback function, and I cannot continue with my code until I have all 8 rows, so I need to halt until all 8 lookups have completed.

This is sort of what I picture right now:

```
db.world.Queue.find(@user.kingdom.troops_queue).on 'success', (troops_queue) ->
    db.world.Queue.find(@user.kingdom.tanks_queue).on 'success', (tanks_queue) ->
        #etc etc
```

This is horrible and gross of course, but I can't think of a way to roll it up into a loop that will allow my code to pause and only continue when the last item has been filled. I was looking into things like jQuery's .each() function, but what is the behavior of that function? Does the code after it immediately continue, or does it wait for the loop to finish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two commonly used ways. The first one is using a library like [caolans async](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
async.parallel
  a: (cb) -> doTaskA cb
  b: (cb) -> doTaskB cb
, (err, {a, b}) ->
  # you can use err, a and b here now
```

The second approach is [streamlinejs](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs):

```
troops_queue = db.world.Queue.find(@user.kingdom.troops_queue).on 'success', _
tanks_queue = db.world.Queue.find(@user.kingdom.tanks_queue).on 'success', _
# go on here
```

However, both solutions assume that the first argument of the callback is the error - if it isn't that way, you should bug the author of the library you're using to change it.

Comment: Option 3: Manual reference counting.

Comment: +1 for `async`.  `async` has a lot of functions besides `parallel`: `waterfall`, `forEach`, etc., all of which are immensely helpful if you're writing asynchronous code.

Comment: async looks usable. I can always write my own functions there to get around the callback issue, and it's still loads cleaner than what I had before. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Use flow control like [after.js](https://github.com/Raynos/after.js)

```
var data = {};
    cb = after(8, function ( ) {
        // handle all 8 results
    }),
    queue = db.world.Queue,
    kingdom = this.user.kingdom;

queue.find(kingdom.troops_queue).on('success', function (result) {
    data["troops_queue"] = result;
    cb();
});

// etc
```

P.S. I fixed that coffeescript for you.

Comment: @thejh streamline is ugly and I presume coco is uglier.

Comment: Coco is more consistent than coffeescript and has cooler additional syntax.

Comment: Yes, I do need to get in the habit of shortening my stuff. :D This was a simple example, but that looks much, much cleaner.

Comment: Hmm, after looks cool, too, but a little bit too low-level for me.

Comment: I just realized that was a language bash and not an example bash. I get the feeling that coffeescript is somewhat unliked, although the issues that the coco project states are not things I've run into yet. Anyway, do you think I should convert my question into regular javascript? The problem exists regardless of the language syntax.

Comment: @NicholasFlynt No. CoffeeScript is close enough to javascript to be readable. Unless you do really obscure hackery. I would however refuse to answer any Script# or Dart questions which are actually javascript questions. The fact that I'm insulting coffeescript is just a joke on the side.

Answer (score 1):

You could organize your queries in a 'successful progression' sequence; this sequence can be used by a continuation-style loop, kinda like this in Javascript:

```
var lookups = [
   function(){ Q.find(@user.kingdom.troops_queue; },
   function(troops_queue){ Q.find(...tanks_queue; },
   function(tanks_queue){ Q.find(...next_queu; },
   ....
];
```

And this 'stratified' sequence can be drewn through the asynchronous mill like

```
function proceedOn( sequence, previous_result ) {       
   var first = sequence[0];
   first( previous_result ).onSuccess( function(result){
     proceedOn( sequence[1..], result );
   } );
}

proceedOn( lookups );
```

(Where I took some poetic liberties on array syntactic sugar)

Comment: @thejh: indeed: it's an array.

Answer (score 1):

I always use [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step) for my projects, it's very clean and nice.

Here's an example of some callbacks in a row:

```
Step(
  function readSelf() {
    fs.readFile(__filename, this);
  },
  function capitalize(err, text) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return text.toUpperCase();
  },
  function showIt(err, newText) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(newText);
  }
);
```

You may also want to do some parallel stuff and only then trigger the callback, fortunately this.parallel() is just the thing for that:

```
Step(
  // Loads two files in parallel
  function loadStuff() {
    fs.readFile(__filename, this.parallel());
    fs.readFile("/etc/passwd", this.parallel());
  },
  // Show the result when done
  function showStuff(err, code, users) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(code);
    console.log(users);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged with "coffescript" some links you can check (long threads!):
[issue241](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/241), [issue287](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/287), [issue350](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/350), [issue1710](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/1710) (and probably some more...)

In a nutshell:

- A user created [this fork](https://web.archive.org/web/20100713082236/http://github.com:80/gfxmonk/coffee-script/tree/deferred), but it's not maintained anymore.
- [Tamejs](https://web.archive.org/web/20130116230210/http://tamejs.org/) or [streamlinejs](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs) are considered good alternatives for now.

Comment: tamejs is considered an opinionated alternative. Flow control mechanisms are better suited.

Comment: Tamejs uses additional syntax and is therefore not usable in coffee. Streamlinejs is better.

Comment: @Raynos: IMHO tamejs is a valid approach to the problem, flow-control mechanism is another approach, is that a fact that they are better? can you paste references?. thejh: not pretty, but usable: https://github.com/maxtaco/tamejs/wiki/Using-tamejs-with-CoffeeScript

Comment: @tokland: Ewwwwww, misuse embedded JS syntax that way? Hurts.

Comment: @tokland If I said it's a fact flow control is better I would start a holy war.

Comment: @Raynos: at least not with me :-) I like both approaches, and I think both have pros and cons.